# snap-store errors

Tags: updates, snap, snap-store

I have a brand new laptop. The first thing I did was uninstall firefox and thunderbird from apt and then firefox from snap-store. I'm not sure if it is related to the errors.

Before I uninstalled firefox from snap-store, it showed some updates are available. After I uninstalled firefox snap-store stopped and then launched again, without updates.

Running from the console I see:
not handling error failed for action refresh: E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

```
17:07:09:0735 Gs  not handling error failed for action refresh: E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  
E: Failed to fetch https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I'm connected to the internet (writing this question on said laptop)

I googled a bit and saw a recommendation to stop and refresh snap-store (`sudo snap refresh snap-store`). Didn't help. Then I saw a recommendation to uninstall snap-store and install again (`sudo snap remove snap-store` and `sudo snap install snap-store`). So I did. Apprently that removed some of the configured repositories above. Now I see this error:

```
17:09:59:0693 Gs  not handling error failed for action refresh: E: Failed to fetch http://il.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-backports/InRelease  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any other suggestions? Also, how do I add the repositories back?

UPDATE: I tried to find where the repositories are defined by searching in /etc and got these errors:

grep: /etc/systemd/system/snap-snapdx2ddesktopx2dintegration-49.mount: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/systemd/system/snap-snapdx2ddesktopx2dintegration-83.mount: No such file or directory

```
grep: /etc/systemd/system/snap-gnomex2d42x2d2204-141.mount: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/systemd/system/snap-gtkx2dcommonx2dthemes-1535.mount: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/systemd/system/snap-gnomex2d3x2d38x2d2004-119.mount: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/systemd/system/snap-snapx2dstore-959.mount: No such file or directory
grep: /etc/systemd/system/snap-gnomex2d3x2d38x2d2004-143.mount: No such file or directory
```